# Why are the input boxes completely overflowing their bounding divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I intend to line up 4 input text boxes housed in 4 equal sized columns in one row of the form. Making use of Bootstrap's grid column classes, I assigned  col-*-3 for medium and large screen sizes to those four input divs. 
Likewise for small and extra small sizes, I assigned them col-*-12  so that the inputs occupy their own whole row. Then my guide wanted those input boxes sizes reduced. I added offset class to the four input and reduced their column span to 6 columns. These were centered appropriately.

However, this change screwed up my small screen layout. Now there are only two inputs in each row, while the other two in the next row.

```css
/* button modification*/

#button-wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ebook-download-button {
  margin: auto 0.5em;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  /* center the block element*/
}

img {
  min-width: 100%;
}

input {
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* square boxes*/

.square-elem {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>



  <form id="registration-form" class="">
    <!--<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="company" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="button-wrapper" style="">
        <div id="ebook-download-button" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
          <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-download form-control square-elem" value=""> DOWNLOAD EBOOK </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- </div>
  -->
  </form>






</body>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhchtnsf/)(Drag the frame) too. It seems the inputs(in each form group div) have completely positioned outside their bounding div box.The intended output should be the four inputs lined side by side in one row. 
What can possibly be the issue here?

Comment: The issue is you have **four** column elements in a row container that are **six** columns wide, 3 from `.col-md-3` and 3 from `.col-md-offset-3`. There are **twelve** columns in a row. You have a total of **24**, so it makes sense that some would reflow below the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is, the offset is still in larger screens,You have to reverse the offsetting for each of the other col-classes .Give col-md-offset-0 to the divs where you specified offset for smaller device

```css
/* button modification*/

#button-wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ebook-download-button {
  margin: auto 0.5em;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  /* center the block element*/
}

img {
  min-width: 100%;
}

input {
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* square boxes*/

.square-elem {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>



  <form id="registration-form" class="">
    <!--<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="company" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="button-wrapper" style="">
        <div id="ebook-download-button" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
          <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-download form-control square-elem" value=""> DOWNLOAD EBOOK </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- </div>
   -->
  </form>






</body>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I really need to read the docs more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

you have classes `col-sm-offset-3` and `col-xs-offset-3`  these classes 'push' the columns with a number of 3 columns. so the inputs have margin-left equal to 3 column widths

see more here > http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

remove those classes and everything will work ok

see here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhchtnsf/1/)
or snippet below

```css
/*Main box*/
div #ebook-registration-box
{
  border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

/* button modification*/
#button-wrapper
{
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}

#ebook-download-button
{
  margin: auto 0.5em;
}

 .inner
{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  
  padding: 0 ;
  
  /* center the block element*/
}

/* fixed height for responsive images
   (does not work)*/ 
img 
{
  
  min-width: 100%;
}

input
{
 
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0px;
}



/* square boxes*/
.square-elem
{
  border-radius: 0px;  
}
/* */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="ebook-registration-box" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" > 
   
  <div id="registration-header" class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-center">
           Register to download the device launch guide
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
   <!-- 4 form elements--> 
 
 
 <form id="registration-form" class="" >
   <!--<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">-->
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6  col-xs-6 ">
   <div class="form-group"> 
   <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
        </div> 
         
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
           <div class="form-group">    
            <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
     </div>
         </div> 
      
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6  col-xs-6 ">
           <div class="form-group">
   <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="company" placeholder="Company">
     </div>
         </div>
      
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    
           <div class="form-group">
      <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="email" placeholder="Email">  
           </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
      
       <!-- Download Button                   -->
     <div class="row">
        <div id="button-wrapper"  style="">
         <div id="ebook-download-button" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">             
          <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-download form-control square-elem"  value=""> DOWNLOAD EBOOK </a>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- </div>-->
    
  </form>
    </div>   
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you were wanting? You just needed to disable the offset for the larger widths and make the offset smaller for xs widths.

```css
#button-wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ebook-download-button {
  margin: auto 0.5em;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  /* center the block element*/
}

img {
  min-width: 100%;
}

input {
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* square boxes*/

.square-elem {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="ebook-registration-box" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" > 
   
  <div id="registration-header" class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-center">
           Register to download the device launch guide
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
   <!-- 4 form elements--> 
 
 
 <form id="registration-form" class="" >
   <!--<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">-->
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 ">
   <div class="form-group"> 
   <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
        </div> 
         
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
           <div class="form-group">    
            <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
     </div>
         </div> 
      
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
           <div class="form-group">
   <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="company" placeholder="Company">
     </div>
         </div>
      
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
           <div class="form-group">
      <input type="input" class="form-control square-elem" id="email" placeholder="Email">  
           </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="button-wrapper"  style="">
         <div id="ebook-download-button" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">             
          <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-download form-control square-elem"  value=""> DOWNLOAD EBOOK </a>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- </div>-->
    
  </form>
    </div>   
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `"form-inline"` class on `<form>` for horizontal form display.